# SQL Query to return new column based on first two columns

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
username    manager  
emp001      emp006   
emp002      emp006  
emp003      emp006   
emp004      emp007  
emp005      emp007   
emp006      emp009   
emp007      emp010    
emp008      emp010   
emp009      emp011      
emp010      null      
emp011      null
```

I would like to create a select query that returns a third column like this - where the new column is based taking the manager item and referring back to the first column and getting manager of that row.

```
username    manager    director
emp001      emp006     emp009             
emp002      emp006     emp009  
emp003      emp006     emp009   
emp004      emp007     emp010  
emp005      emp007     emp010   
emp006      emp009     emp011   
emp007      emp010     null   
emp008      emp010     null    
emp009      emp011     null    
emp010      null       null
emp011      null       null
```

I'm lost on this one.

Thanks for any advise. I've tried various combinations of selects and joins but nothing seems to do what I want.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
Select      E.UserName, E.Manager, M.Manager As Director
From        YourTable   E
Left Join   YourTable   M   On  E.Manager = M.UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select e1.id, e1.managerId, e2.managerId
from employees e1
left join employees e2 on (e1.manager = e2.employee)
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the same table using another alias name :

```
select a.username,a.manager,b.manager as director
from TableName a left join
TableName b on a.manager=b.username
```

Result:

```
username    manager     director
emp001      emp006      emp009
emp002      emp006      emp009
emp003      emp006      emp009
emp004      emp007      emp010
emp005      emp007      emp010
emp006      emp009      emp011
emp007      emp010      (null)
emp008      emp010      (null)
emp009      emp011      (null)
emp010      (null)      (null)
emp011      (null)      (null)
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01e684/4)